# How to get ApplicationContext in ReactContextBaseJavaModule?

Tags: android, react-native

I am building a React Native Application, in a react native module in Android code I wish to access the path for cache files used by Android code.

At some point I am writing (from the native code) a json file in the cache of the app data, I use `getApplicationContext()` to get the context and apply `getCacheDir()` to get the path of the cache files.

In a class extending `ReactContextBaseJavaModule` I want to access the Application context to get the cache files path, but when invoking `getApplicationContext()` on the React context and using `getCacheDir()` the path returned is not the same as the one returned before.

What is the way to get the Global context in a react native module ?

Cheers

Comment: Maybe solution here : https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3895

Answer (score 3):

`ReactApplicationContext` is passed in to the constructor of your class that extends `ReactContextBaseJavaModule`. You can call `ReactApplicationContext.getApplicationContext()` to get the `ApplicationContext`.

Comment: I have an issue related to this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65948333/null-object-reference-while-using-googlesignin. please check it put mate

Answer (score 2):

@Alan answer is great but I wanted to add a code snippet for more clarity :

```
public class FlashModule extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
   Context context;

   FlashModule(ReactApplicationContext context) {
       super(context);
       this.context = context.getApplicationContext(); // This is where you get the context
   }

   @Override
   public String getName() {
      return "FlashModule";
   }
}
```